# PHP Array to Javascript Object no array after console.log

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

Now there are plenty of people with the same issue and their resolutions have not worked.

## Problem

I have a list of Times coming back from a REST call. They are created exactly as they should, except I want them to be stored into a JavaScript Array.

## PHP

```
    function getOpenAppts() 
{
    global $wpdb;
    $final_array = "";
    $td = date('m/d/Y');
    $datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow');
    $tm = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
    $startDate = $td;
    $endDate = $tm;
    $apptTypeID = "23";
    $get_loc = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT provid,id FROM location');
    foreach($get_loc as $val){
    // call to Athena to get open appointments
        $res = getOpenAppointments($val->id, $val->provid, $startDate, $endDate, $apptTypeID);
        //print_r($res);

        // if we got some appointments back strip any that started before now
        if (array_key_exists('totalcount', $res) && $res['appointments'] > 0)
        {
            $tzStr = "America/Los_Angeles";
            $tzObject = new DateTimeZone($tzStr);
            $nowDT = new DateTime();
            $nowDT->setTimezone($tzObject);
            //print_r($nowDT);
            //print_r("\n");
            $appts = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($res['appointments']); $i++)
            {
                $apptDT = new DateTime($res['appointments'][$i]['date']." ".$res['appointments'][$i]['starttime'], $tzObject);
                //print_r($apptDT);
                //print_r("\n");
                if ($nowDT < $apptDT)
                    $appts[] = $res['appointments'][$i];
            }
        }

        if (count($appts) > 0)
            foreach($appts as $data) {
                $final_array[] = $data;
        }

        else
            $res; // something went wrong. return error message
    }
    echo json_encode($final_array);
}
```

## Header.php

```
<script>
    var times = <?php getOpenAppts(); ?>;
    console.log(times); //Will display properly
</script>
```

[image]
That is exactly how it should come back!

But.. When I run a console on the variable times (which is in the header making it a global variable. I get this.
[image]

It should give me the exact same list that the console.log gave me.

## What I Have tried

I ran:

```
PARSE.json(times);
```

No effect...

I did in PHP:

```
json_encode(json_decode($appts),true);
```

No effect...

What part of this process is incorrect?

Comment: Is that PHP what is inside the function `getOpenAppts()`?

Comment: Maybe somewhere else you are overriding it? Try changing its name to something unusual and keep the console.log

Comment: Just updated the PHP

Comment: @DiogoSgrillo I will do that right now!! Didnt think about that.

Comment: To me the strange thing is, the js variable `times` logs properly. So I would expect the `window.times` to show the same in the log when you simply enter `times` => Unless it's global and so ... overridden ... hence ... global issue? no?

Comment: I don't think this has something to do with PHP at all!

Comment: In my main.js file, it had a times = ""; FML... Thanks everyone! @DiogoSgrillo can you post an answer so I can thumbs it up a million!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `time` as a global variable.

Since the `console.log` right after the declaration prints everything fine, you are probably overriding its value somewhere after.

Avoid the most you can global variables, they're evil :)